# Python: Do pandas.DataFrame.comprod() and numpy.comprod() handle numerical underflow?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, underflow

Specifically, are these cumulative product functions in `pandas` and `numpy` implemented in a robust way to handle underflow when multiplying lots of small numbers together? For example, are they using the log-sum-exp trick?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check this pretty easily.  For example, set `x = np.array([1e-5, 1e-30, 1e-100, 1e-200, 1e50, 1e150])`, and compare `np.cumprod(x)` with `np.exp(np.cumsum(np.log(x)))`.

Comment: Yes I did something similar but wasn't sure where the theoretical bounds are, or if it was just hitting the limit of my platoform (machine/os/etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  @warren-weckesser 's comment shows this to not work.

```
np.array([1e-5, 1e-30, 1e-100, 1e-200, 1e50, 1e150]).cumprod()

# returns
array([1.0e-005, 1.0e-035, 1.0e-135, 0.0e+000, 0.0e+000, 0.0e+000])
```

The reason is that numpy floats support a smallest positive value of 2**-1022, or about  2.225e-308.  Once your calculation becomes smaller than that, it is dropped to zero, which is what we see in the above output.  The same is true for pandas.